# How to convert minizip wrapper to unicode?

Tags: c++, c, zlib

I am trying to use minzip wrapper from [http://www.zlib.net/] for zipping a folder. It works fine  as long as the file names are in english. Has anyone tried to modify minizip to support unicode?

The modified code is posted below. The problem is with this function, the second argument takes const char* as the input. When I do the conversion  it looses data and files names are not the same.

eg: Chinese-統一碼.txt becomes Chinese-t+ƒS+Çtáü.txt inside zip.

```
err = zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64(  zf,outstr.c_str(),&zi,
                                        NULL,0,NULL,0,NULL /* comment*/,
                                        (opt_compress_level != 0) ? Z_DEFLATED : 0,
                                        opt_compress_level,0,
                                        /* -MAX_WBITS, DEF_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY, */
                                        -MAX_WBITS, DEF_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY,
                                        password,crcFile, zip64);








minizip.c
Version 1.1, February 14h, 2010
sample part of the MiniZip project - ( http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html )

Copyright (C) 1998-2010 Gilles Vollant (minizip) ( http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html )

Modifications of Unzip for Zip64
Copyright (C) 2007-2008 Even Rouault

Modifications for Zip64 support on both zip and unzip
Copyright (C) 2009-2010 Mathias Svensson ( http://result42.com )
*/


#if (!defined(_WIN32)) && (!defined(WIN32)) && (!defined(__APPLE__))
#ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
#define __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
#endif
#ifndef __USE_LARGEFILE64
#define __USE_LARGEFILE64
#endif
#ifndef _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#endif
#ifndef _FILE_OFFSET_BIT
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BIT 64
#endif
#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__
// In darwin and perhaps other BSD variants off_t is a 64 bit value, hence no need for specific 64 bit functions
#define FOPEN_FUNC(filename, mode) fopen(filename, mode)
#define FTELLO_FUNC(stream) ftello(stream)
#define FSEEKO_FUNC(stream, offset, origin) fseeko(stream, offset, origin)
#else
#define FOPEN_FUNC(filename, mode) fopen64(filename, mode)
#define FTELLO_FUNC(stream) ftello64(stream)
#define FSEEKO_FUNC(stream, offset, origin) fseeko64(stream, offset, origin)
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
# include <direct.h>
# include <io.h>
#define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
# include <unistd.h>
# include <utime.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
#endif

#include "zip.h"
#include "Shlwapi.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#define USEWIN32IOAPI
#include "iowin32.h"
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

#define WRITEBUFFERSIZE (16384)
#define MAXFILENAME (256)

#ifdef _WIN32
uLong filetime(
    wchar_t *f,                /* name of file to get info on */
    tm_zip *tmzip,             /* return value: access, modific. and creation times */
    uLong *dt)           /* dostime */
{
    int ret = 0;
    {
        FILETIME ftLocal;
        HANDLE hFind;
        _WIN32_FIND_DATAW ff32;

        hFind = FindFirstFileW(f,&ff32);
        if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&(ff32.ftLastWriteTime),&ftLocal);
            FileTimeToDosDateTime(&ftLocal,((LPWORD)dt)+1,((LPWORD)dt)+0);
            FindClose(hFind);
            ret = 1;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
#else
#ifdef unix || __APPLE__
uLong filetime(f, tmzip, dt)
    char *f;               /* name of file to get info on */
tm_zip *tmzip;         /* return value: access, modific. and creation times */
uLong *dt;             /* dostime */
{
    int ret=0;
    struct stat s;        /* results of stat() */
    struct tm* filedate;
    time_t tm_t=0;

    if (strcmp(f,"-")!=0)
    {
        char name[MAXFILENAME+1];
        int len = strlen(f);
        if (len > MAXFILENAME)
            len = MAXFILENAME;

        strncpy(name, f,MAXFILENAME-1);
        /* strncpy doesnt append the trailing NULL, of the string is too long. */
        name[ MAXFILENAME ] = '\0';

        if (name[len - 1] == '/')
            name[len - 1] = '\0';
        /* not all systems allow stat'ing a file with / appended */
        if (stat(name,&s)==0)
        {
            tm_t = s.st_mtime;
            ret = 1;
        }
    }
    filedate = localtime(&tm_t);

    tmzip->tm_sec  = filedate->tm_sec;
    tmzip->tm_min  = filedate->tm_min;
    tmzip->tm_hour = filedate->tm_hour;
    tmzip->tm_mday = filedate->tm_mday;
    tmzip->tm_mon  = filedate->tm_mon ;
    tmzip->tm_year = filedate->tm_year;

    return ret;
}
#else
uLong filetime(f, tmzip, dt)
    char *f;                /* name of file to get info on */
tm_zip *tmzip;             /* return value: access, modific. and creation times */
uLong *dt;             /* dostime */
{
    return 0;
}
#endif
#endif

void addFileToList(list<wstring>& fileList, const wstring& directory, const set<wstring>& excludeFilterSet, const wstring& fileName )
{
    wstring fileExtension = fileName.substr(fileName.find_last_of(L".") + 1);
    if (!fileExtension.empty()) 
    {
        if (excludeFilterSet.find(fileExtension) != excludeFilterSet.end()) return;
    } 

    fileList.push_back(directory + fileName);
}

void GetFileListing(list<wstring>& fileList, wstring directory,const set<wstring>& excludeFilterSet,bool recursively=true)
{
    directory = directory + L"\\";
    wstring filter = directory + L"*";

    _WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(filter.c_str(), &FindFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            //cout << "Invalid file handle for filter " << filter << ". Error is " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) 
        {
            if ((recursively) && (wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L".") != 0) && (wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L"..") != 0))
            {
                GetFileListing(fileList, directory + FindFileData.cFileName, excludeFilterSet);
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            addFileToList(fileList, directory, excludeFilterSet,FindFileData.cFileName);
        }
    } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0);

    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);

    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        //cout << "FindNextFile error. Error is "<< dwError << endl;
    }
}


int check_exist_file(wchar_t* filename)
{
    FILE* ftestexist;
    int ret = 1;
    //ftestexist = FOPEN_FUNC(filename,"rb");
    ftestexist = _wfopen(filename,L"rb");
    if (ftestexist==NULL)
        ret = 0;
    else
        fclose(ftestexist);
    return ret;
}

/* calculate the CRC32 of a file,
because to encrypt a file, we need known the CRC32 of the file before */
int getFileCrc(const wchar_t * filenameinzip,void*buf,unsigned long size_buf,unsigned long* result_crc)
{
    unsigned long calculate_crc=0;
    int err=ZIP_OK;
    //FILE * fin = FOPEN_FUNC(filenameinzip,"rb");
    FILE * fin = _wfopen(filenameinzip,L"rb");

    unsigned long size_read = 0;
    unsigned long total_read = 0;
    if (fin==NULL)
    {
        err = ZIP_ERRNO;
    }

    if (err == ZIP_OK)
        do
        {
            err = ZIP_OK;
            size_read = (int)fread(buf,1,size_buf,fin);
            if (size_read < size_buf)
                if (feof(fin)==0)
                {
                    printf("error in reading %s\n",filenameinzip);
                    err = ZIP_ERRNO;
                }

                if (size_read>0)
                    calculate_crc = crc32(calculate_crc,(const Bytef *)buf,size_read);
                total_read += size_read;

        } while ((err == ZIP_OK) && (size_read>0));

        if (fin)
            fclose(fin);

        *result_crc=calculate_crc;
        printf("file %s crc %lx\n", filenameinzip, calculate_crc);
        return err;
}

int isLargeFile(const wchar_t * filename)
{
    int largeFile = 0;
    ZPOS64_T pos = 0;
    //FILE* pFile = FOPEN_FUNC(filename, "rb");
    FILE* pFile = _wfopen(filename, L"rb");

    if(pFile != NULL)
    {
        int n = FSEEKO_FUNC(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        pos = FTELLO_FUNC(pFile);

        printf("File : %s is %lld bytes\n", filename, pos);

        if(pos >= 0xffffffff)
            largeFile = 1;

        fclose(pFile);
    }

    return largeFile;
}

void split( const wstring& text, wchar_t delimiter,set<wstring>& result )
{
    wstring::size_type start = 0;
    wstring::size_type end   = text.find( delimiter, start );
    wstring token;

    while( end != wstring::npos )
    {
        token = text.substr( start, end - start );
        token.erase(0,2);
        result.insert( token );
        start = end + 1;
        end   = text.find( delimiter, start );
    }

    // Add the last string
    token = text.substr(start);
    token = token.erase(0,2);
    result.insert(token);
}

//Do not call me.
long getUTF8size(const wchar_t *string){
    if (!string)
        return 0;
    long res=0;
    for (;*string;string++){
        if (*string<0x80)
            res++;
        else if (*string<0x800)
            res+=2;
        else
            res+=3;
    }
    return res;
}

char *WChar_to_UTF8(const wchar_t *string){
    long fSize=getUTF8size(string);
    char *res=new char[fSize+1];
    res[fSize]=0;
    if (!string)
        return res;
    long b=0;
    for (;*string;string++,b++){
        if (*string<0x80)
            res[b]=(char)*string;
        else if (*string<0x800){
            res[b++]=(*string>>6)|192;
            res[b]=*string&63|128;
        }else{
            res[b++]=(*string>>12)|224;
            res[b++]=((*string&4095)>>6)|128;
            res[b]=*string&63|128;
        }
    }
    return res;
}


std::string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo( size_needed, 0 );
    WideCharToMultiByte                  (CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}


wstring zipper( const wstring& directoryPath, const wstring& strExcludeFilter, wstring & zipFileName )
{
    int opt_overwrite=0,opt_compress_level=Z_BEST_COMPRESSION,opt_exclude_path=0,err=0,size_buf=0;
    void* buf=NULL;
    const char* password=NULL;
    list<wstring> fileList;
    DWORD dwRet;

    wchar_t cCurrentPath[MAX_PATH];
    dwRet = GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, cCurrentPath);
    if( dwRet == 0 )
    {
        return wstring();
    }

    // Change the directory to the current folder
    _wchdir(directoryPath.c_str());
    set<wstring> excludeFilterSet;
    split(strExcludeFilter,'|',excludeFilterSet);

    GetFileListing(fileList, directoryPath,excludeFilterSet);
    opt_overwrite = 1;

    size_buf = WRITEBUFFERSIZE;
    buf = (void*)malloc(size_buf);
    if (buf==NULL) return wstring();

    wchar_t tempDirPath[MAX_PATH];
    dwRet = GetTempPathW (MAX_PATH, tempDirPath);
    if( dwRet == 0 ) return wstring();

    wstring directoryName,zipFilePath;
    _WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(directoryPath.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) 
    {
        directoryName = FindFileData.cFileName;
    }

    zipFilePath = wstring(tempDirPath)+L"\\"+directoryName+L".zip";
    zipFile zf;
    int errclose;

    #ifdef USEWIN32IOAPI
        zlib_filefunc64_def ffunc;
        fill_win32_filefunc64W (&ffunc);
        zf = zipOpen2_64(zipFilePath.c_str(),(opt_overwrite==2) ? 2 : 0,NULL,&ffunc);
    #   else
        zf = zipOpen64(zipFilePath.c_str(),(opt_overwrite==2) ? 2 : 0);
    #   endif

    if (zf == NULL)
    {
        //printf("error opening %s\n",filename_try);
        err= ZIP_ERRNO;
    }
    else
    {
        //printf("creating %s\n",filename_try);
    }

    for(list<wstring>::iterator it = fileList.begin() ; it!=fileList.end();++it) 
    {
        FILE * fin;
        int size_read;
        //const char* filenameinzip = (*it).c_str();
        wstring filenameinzip = (*it).c_str();
        wchar_t szOut[MAX_PATH];

        PathRelativePathToW(szOut,
                            directoryPath.c_str(),
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY,
                            filenameinzip.c_str(),
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);

        wchar_t *savefilenameinzip;
        zip_fileinfo zi;
        unsigned long crcFile=0;
        int zip64 = 0;

        zi.tmz_date.tm_sec = zi.tmz_date.tm_min = zi.tmz_date.tm_hour =
            zi.tmz_date.tm_mday = zi.tmz_date.tm_mon = zi.tmz_date.tm_year = 0;
        zi.dosDate = 0;
        zi.internal_fa = 0;
    zi.external_fa = 0;
        filetime(szOut,&zi.tmz_date,&zi.dosDate);

        if ((password != NULL) && (err==ZIP_OK))
            err = getFileCrc(szOut,buf,size_buf,&crcFile);

        zip64 = isLargeFile(szOut);

        /* The path name saved, should not include a leading slash. */
        /*if it did, windows/xp and dynazip couldn't read the zip file. */
        savefilenameinzip = szOut;
        while( savefilenameinzip[0] == '\\' || savefilenameinzip[0] == '/' )
        {
            savefilenameinzip++;
        }

        string outstr = utf8_encode(savefilenameinzip);
        //char * op = (char*)outstr.c_str();


        err = zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64(  zf,outstr.c_str(),&zi,
                                        NULL,0,NULL,0,NULL /* comment*/,
                                        (opt_compress_level != 0) ? Z_DEFLATED : 0,
                                        opt_compress_level,0,
                                        /* -MAX_WBITS, DEF_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY, */
                                        -MAX_WBITS, DEF_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY,
                                        password,crcFile, zip64);

        if (err != ZIP_OK)
        {
            //printf("error in opening %s in zipfile\n",szOut);
        }
        else
        {
            //fin = FOPEN_FUNC(szOut,"rb");
            fin = _wfopen(szOut,L"rb");

            if (fin==NULL)
            {
                err=ZIP_ERRNO;
                //printf("error in opening %s for reading\n",szOut);
            }
        }

        if (err == ZIP_OK)
            do
            {
                err = ZIP_OK;
                size_read = (int)fread(buf,1,size_buf,fin);
                if (size_read < size_buf)
                    if (feof(fin)==0)
                    {
                        //printf("error in reading %s\n",szOut);
                        err = ZIP_ERRNO;
                    }

                    if (size_read>0)
                    {
                        err = zipWriteInFileInZip (zf,buf,size_read);
                        if (err<0)
                        {
                            //printf("error in writing %s in the zipfile\n",szOut);
                        }

                    }
            } while ((err == ZIP_OK) && (size_read>0));

            if (fin)
                fclose(fin);

            if (err<0)
                err=ZIP_ERRNO;
            else
            {
                err = zipCloseFileInZip(zf);
                if (err!=ZIP_OK)
                {
                    //printf("error in closing %s in the zipfile\n",szOut);
                }
            }
    }

    errclose = zipClose(zf,NULL);
    if (errclose != ZIP_OK)
    {
        //printf("error in closing %s\n",filename_try);
    }

    free(buf);
    // Change back the executabe context
    _wchdir(cCurrentPath);
    return zipFilePath;
}
```

Comment: Even I tried to modify zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64 and all it's related api's to accept wchar_t* as the input. Also modified the memory allocation and string length calculation to equivalent wchar_t functions.But after doing all these changes the final zip says corrupted header. So that is why I haven't touched this function and just converted wchar_t * string to equivalent char* string.

Comment: Other than as an attribute of "Mac specific data", the ZIP specification has no notion of character encoding at all, so I don't see how minizip or any other library could possibly do such a thing in a well-defined manner. Filenames, as far as ZIP is concerned, are up to 64k "bytes" (whatever that is) with some requirements such as no drive letters and forward slashes instead of backslashes. You could probably transform your Chinese characters into UTF-8 (and back), which is "just bytes", but I'm not sure how "valid" this is.

Comment: @Damon, your statement is incorrect. The [definition of the ZIP format](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) used to refer to “code page 437”, but now there are mechanisms to store e.g. UTF-8 file names. See Appendix D of the text referenced above. Not sure about application support, or library support, but the standard at least has room for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The official way to store UTF-8 file names in a ZIP file, according to [the standard](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), is setting “general purpose bit 11”. Looking at the minizip sources, it seems to me that minizip will not set this bit for you at any time, and that `zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64` provides no way to pass this bit. There is however a `zipOpenNewFileInZip4_64` which accepts two more arguments, `versionMadeBy` and `flagBase`. So you might be able to store UTF-8 file names in accordance with the standard by changing your call to

```
err = zipOpenNewFileInZip4_64(zf, outstr.c_str(), […], crcFile, 36, 1<<11, zip64);
```

This is assuming that `outstr` actually does contain a valid UTF-8 encoding of your file name, which the source code suggests it should, but which I haven't verified. I suggest you print the hexadecimal values of the bytes of `outstr` to verify this. Unless I garbled the string in the process, your “統一碼.txt” should become `e7 b5 b1 e4 b8 80 e7 a2 bc 2e 74 78 74` in hexadecimal UTF-8.

For details on this `versionMadeBy` field (which I set to `36` in my call), look at section 4.4.2 of the standard. It depends on what platform you are using, what format the file attributes from `zipfi` argument (`&zi` in your case) have, and what version of the standard everything adhers to. As you are using unicode file names, I'd say you're using version 6.3.* of the standard, so the lower byte should be `36`. And as the `minizip.c` wrapper does not store any file attributes at all, you don't have to specify a platform there. The lack of attributes can be seen from these lines:

```
    zi.internal_fa = 0;
    zi.external_fa = 0;
```

Note that even though the standard does provide a way to denote unicode file names, that part has only been added in 2006, and there might still be many ZIP applications out there which do not support it. So even if your archive is correct, your unzip utility might still unzip this file incorrectly, interpreting the UTF-8 bytes as codepage 437 or latin 1 or similar.

Comment: Thanks MvG! I am trying to modify the source and update you the results!

Comment: MvG , Any idea about the 17th argument 'uLong versionMadeBy' in zipOpenNewFileInZip4_64? What value should be passed to this?

Comment: @RP.: I missed that `versionMadeBy` field. Edited my answer to suggest a suitable value.

Comment: I have one small issue. Using this api , default windows-7 zip program is not able to unzip properly. But 7zip utility is able to unzip it properly..Any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: @RP.: By “default windows-7 zip program” you mean explorer, right? In any case, I'd *assume* this is due to the application not supporting a recent enough version of the specification. There does not seem to be a value for the “version needed to extract” field which would ensure support for this. If Windows can create Unicode zips, and can extract these itself, then you could probably open the resulting zip in a hex editor, compare it against the spec and see *how* they implement their Unicode support. Probably you could duplicate that in your code.

Comment: Yes the "Send to Compressed folder" in windows explorer. But what I noticed is that even it cannot handle file names with Chinese characters in it. As you mentioned , the "Send to Compressed folder" application may not be supporting the latest zip standard for Unicode support. When I used zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64(...) api I was able to open the compressed folder in explorer even though it had issues with file names other than English. Let me explore bit more on this!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/476740/error-while-zipping-files-with-unicode-characters-in-names-with-win7s-send-to

Comment: I was not able to open the compressed folder in explorer due to small bug which went unnoticed when I modified the original minizip source! In "zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64" the file name (i.e. outstr) had "./" at the beginning. Windows can't handle if the file name begins with "./" Now explorer can open the compressed folder.

Comment: The best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a program to handle UTF-8 correctly isn't trivial, take a look at the [Unicode FAQ](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html). A program that handles possibly malicious data (like compressing/uncompressing) must be extra careful. A worthwhile endeavor, definitely not trivial.

Comment: The unicode here is only in the file names. And the question only refers to compressing, not uncompressing. So this only entails converting some known encoding local file name into its UTF-8 representation. I see no security risk there. For uncompressing, as long as the UTF-8 decoder detects and handles invalid input, the rest should work just as it used to. So while I agree in general, the changes in this particular case seem comparatively easy and safe.