# Is there any universal way to convert wstring to std::string considering all possible encoding?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, character-encoding

I am using following api to encode wstring to string,

```
string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr) 
{ 
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    vector<char> buf(len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, &buf[0], len, 0, 0);
    return std::string(buf.begin(), buf.end());
}
```

This encoding works fine as long it is executed in Windows machine with system locale as

English.

Now, If I try to use this in Japanese windows the converted string gets corrupted. What  I understood is that, Japanese windows uses Shift-JIS encding.
If I modify the API to take code page as the argument then it works.

```
string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    UINT codePage = GetACP();
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    vector<char> buf(len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, &buf[0], len, 0, 0);
    return std::string(buf.begin(), buf.end());
}
```

But it fails again If I use Japanese or Chinese characters in windows machine with default system locale as english. Basically I have to convert using CP_UTF8. What if I have to support following code pages?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there any universal way to convert wstring to string considering all possible encodings?

Comment: What is the wstring encoded in?

Comment: What makes you think that `wstring` that you converted into `string` in `UTF-8` is corrupted? Can you give some concrete example of your input and output (preferably just 1-2 symbols with their bytestream values - both input and output)?

Comment: Basically I convert UTF-8 encoded std::string to const char* and then will pass to a zipping library which has the provision for utf-8 file names. So if I use the first API in Japanese machine with a file name as 'サンプル ピクチャ - コピー (10)' final zip has the corrupted file name '繧ｵ繝ｳ繝励Ν 繝斐け繝√Ε - 繧ｳ繝斐・ (10)'. If I use the second api, it shows properly.

Comment: @RP. : That still sounds like a problem with the zipping library. The fact that it can _store_ filenames in UTF8 doesn't necessarily mean that it will _accept_ filenames in UTF8. It sounds like the library accepts filenames in the local character set (`CP_OEM`) and converts that to `CP_UTF8`.

Comment: @MSalters, I had another SO question where I discussed about the UTF8 support in the zipping library, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625784/how-to-convert-minizip-wrapper-to-unicode/14628171?noredirect=1#comment20987464_14628171.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, I think it should be in Shift-JIS when used in Japanese windows. Basically GetACP() returns the Codepage: 932

Comment: @RP.: [Shift-JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) is an 8-bit encoding. Why would Windows put that in a wstring? Where does this string come from?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, When this application is executed in Japanese Windows 7, It tries to read some of the file/folder name which are in Japanese and that name will be stored in wstring. Since the GetACP() returns code page 932(Shift-JIS) , I guess the stored name in wstring has Shift-JIS encoding.. Correct me if I am wrong..

Answer (score 1):

No. Many encodings of `std::string` cover only a subset of the `wstring` character set. E.g. the common choices of `ISO-8859-1` and Unicode mean that most `wchar_t` values do not have a `char` equivalent. There's just no サ in ISO-8859-1, for instance.