# Minizip and Unicode for filenames

Tags: c, windows, character-encoding

I'm trying to compress files with non ASCII file names with [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html). If a file with a troublesome file name, that is a name with at least one charactar that is not in ASCII is compressed, the name of the file in the archive is messed up. I red [How to convert minizip wrapper to unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625784/how-to-convert-minizip-wrapper-to-unicode) and changed the source code so that flag 11 is set to true but it made no different.

An example to illustrate the problem:

The file `中文` is named `S+í¦vt` in the zip archive.

Or in hex:

`\x53\x2B\xA1\xB5\xFB\xE7` to `\x53\x2b\xed\xa6\x76\x74`
The first two hexs are the same but not the last four.  `\x53\x2b\xed\xa6\x76\x74` is `S+í¦vt` in `window 1252`

The file name in the program is hard coded to `\x53\x2B\xA1\xB5\xFB\xE7`(中文) to remove the risk that the input is incorrect.

Files with only ASCII characters in their file name are named as they should in the zip archive. On the ground that the name of the file in the zip archive is longer the the original file name , I made the assumption that another encoding then UTF-8 is used.

Since all symbols in a computers are in fact only binary strings, I hope that one hex string will output the correct file name. The problem here is that I do not know how the file names are encoded in a zip archive.

Does anyone have a clue how to do the translation from hex/UTF-8to the correct one and which encoding that are used?

I think the zip archive used the OS standard encoding which in my case is Windows-1252.

```
 const char kChineseSampleText[] = "\x53\x2B\xA1\xB5\xFB\xE7";

 if ( open_file( zipF, kChineseSampleText ) )
 {
     //write to file
 }



 bool open_file( const zipFile zipFile, const char* fileName)
 {
     zip_fileinfo zfi;
     int status = zipOpenNewFileInZip( zipFile, fileName , NULL, &zfi, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, Z_DEFLATED,  Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION );

      if( status != ZIP_OK ) 
      {     
           zipClose( zipFile, NULL ); 
           return false;
      } 
      true;
 }
```

Comment: Please show your code for calling this library. Are you compiling with _UNICODE or not?

Comment: Code is now in my post!
I'm compiling with 
//#ifndef _UNICODE
//#define _UNICODE
//#endif

but it does not affect the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window's standard compress program can not handle Unicode so it read the binary string as window-1252. 7-zip interpret the binary string in Unicode!

So it turns out that my program worked the whole time. The only thing I did was setting flag 11 to true. I did not modified anything else, like using a wchar_t pointer instead of a char*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider from where you are taking file name. Normally, WINAPI functions does have a ANSI and a Unicode version, identified by a suffix 'A' or 'W', respectively. You normally can't see that because it's compiler work. You can force it to ANSI by attaching an 'A' to the function, like `FindNextFileA` (well, I think you are listing a folder with `FindFirstFile`).

If you can't identify wichever is the source format, call `IsTextUnicode(fileName, fileNameSize, NULL)` to check if the file name is in Unicode format. If it is, call `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP, 0, fileName, fileNameSize, ansiFileName, ansiFileNameSize, 0, NULL)`.

Hope this helps and sorry for bad english.

Comment: I'm using the function unzGoToFirstFile to find a file. unzGoToFirstFileA or unzGoToFirstFileW gave me compiling errors!

Comment: Noo, sorry, I meant that this applies only to WINAPI (functions directly from Windows), things may look different in 3rd part libraries. I'll edit my answer to cover another thing I forgot.

Comment: Can you load the file into memory and then write to zip? So you can "translate" the file name before creation. And, from where did you got that code? I got E4B8 ADE6 9687 in UTF8...